# Why isn't require("filename") working?

Tags: perl, require

I've inherited some Perl code that runs on a Linux server just fine. I'm in the process of getting it to run on Windows XP, ActiveState Perl 5.16.2, and a BitNami WAMP stack. (Note: this setup is already running my Perl .cgi programs so this is a working setup.)

Anyway the "main" Perl program--let's call it main.cgi--has this statement:

```
require("extra/stuff_1.cgi");
```

When main.cgi runs, an error occurs:

```
C:/BitNami/apache2/cgi-bin/extra/stuff_1.cgi did not return a true value at C:/BitNami/apache2/cgi-bin/main.cgi line XX.
```

Now here's what is weird: stuff_1.cgi ends with 1; (i.e., it is the last line in the file)!

I've even commented out the code in the functions within stuff_1.cgi -- which are mostly functions with Here Documents, e.g.

```
sub func {

return <<EOF;
...
EOF
}
```

making it contain just

```
sub func {
#
#return <<EOF;
#...
#EOF
}
```

etc.

and yet the "did not return a true value" still occurs!

However if I delete all the code so stuff_1.cgi contains

```
1;
```

the error goes away (as it should).

stuff_1.cgi passes `perl -c`, even with `use strict` and `use warnings`

ETA: If I copy the contents of stuff_1.cgi and paste it into main.cgi (replacing the `require` statement), the code works just fine.

I've never seen anything like this before; what could possibly be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

### Why is the debugger not working (ActiveState or Strawberry Perl under Windows)?

[Why is the debugger not working [ActiveState or Strawberry Perl under Windows]?](http://www.epic-ide.org/faq.php#debug)

> A recent release of PathTools (part of Perl distribution, file Cwd.pm) unfortunately contains a bug which breaks EPIC's debugger frontend. The specific symptom is the error message "perl5db.pl did not return a true value." - to see this message, you should enable the "debugger console" in EPIC Preferences. Furthermore, if you have this problem, debugging doesn't work at all. To fix it, you must edit Cwd.pm of your Perl distribution and remove the offending "eval" keyword from one line, as described in this bug report. DO NOT attempt to fix it by adding Perl's "lib" directory to your project's include path, as this will cause all breakpoints to be ignored!

Comment: Interesting. However my Cwd.pm does not have this issue.

Comment: This issue appears to be caused by the BitNami WAMP stack. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what I've encountered is a defect in ActiveState's version of Perl.

Anyway--after spending way too much time on this--the only way I could get it to work is by replacing

```
require 'extra\stuff_1.cgi';
```

with

```
eval { require 'extra\stuff_1.cgi' };
```

I dislike having to do this but it's time to move on!